# How can I dump all query variables in a perl script like PHP's print_r($_GET)?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl script that I am running from a browser. I'm passing query variables to it, but the query variables are showing up like `johndoe%40test%2Ecom` instead of `johndoe@test.com`

I would like to debug the variables to see how they are showing up in the beginning of the script.

In PHP it would be when accessing the url:

```
http://localhost/dump-variables.php?foo=1&bar=2&bis=johndoe%40test%2Ecom
```

The PHP script would include this code:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_GET);
```

And the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [bar] => 2
    [bis] => johndoe@test.com
)
```

Perl version : 5.010001

#### Important Note

I don't have any special access (root / sudo) on the system I'm working on - so modules may have to be included via source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged this CGI, so I'll first suggest [using something more efficient](http://plackperl.org/).

But if you are going to use CGI, and assuming the use of CGI.pm, then (from the [CGI.pm docs](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#FETCHING-THE-PARAMETER-LIST-AS-A-HASH%3a)):

```
use CGI;
use Data::Dump qw/ddx/;
my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header('text/plain');
my %params = $q->Vars;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"; # had to add this

ddx \%params;
```

Comment: I changed `use CGI` to `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)` and now I'm getting `Can't locate object method "new" via package "CGI" at query-vars.pl line 6.` which corresponds to the line `my $q = CGI->new();`

Comment: @cwd — CGI::Carp is a module for spitting error messages out to the client when using CGI. As far as I know, it doesn't provide any basic CGI handling so you still need CGI itself. You can *add* CGI::Carp, but don't replace CGI with it.

Comment: When I tried to add it the I just got an error 500 without any help on what was wrong :(

Comment: Got it. Premature end of script headers ?

Comment: It's possible that Data::Dump is not installed. You might be better off using Data::Dumper since it is bundled with Perl.

Comment: @gpojd - I downloaded the source so I think that part is ok

Comment: @cwd — Usually means something went wrong before the content-type header came out. Run the script on the command line to see what it actually outputs.

Comment: @Quentin - how do you simulate query variables on the command line?

Comment: With CGI.pm…  ./script.cgi foo=bar

Comment: Make sure the permissions on the script are set correctly. If it is not executable then it will never get run, and the server will report exactly that message. Use `chmod` with a mask of something like `0755`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Data::Printer  http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer
Just add

```
 use DDP;
  ...

 p $_GET
```

Comment: Where does `$_GET` come from? It appears in the question as an example of how the task would be achieved in PHP.

Comment: I downloaded the source to the directory which contains the script and added `use Printer` (I tried `use DDP`) but it is not installed by default. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh. I thought $_GET was a variable that he was using in PHP.

Comment: @cwd — the module is called `Data::Printer`. Don't download the source. Install it with cpan (or better yet, cpanm).

Comment: @jmcneirney — It's a superglobal, an array automatically populated with data from the query string.

Comment: @jmcneirney - I updated the question but I'm an unprivileged user on the system so not sure if I can use cpan